# Chart.setOptions() Bug in Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am working on a project using KendoUI for HTML5. I noticed a bug in chart widget where ***setOptions()*** does not work all the time. Here is the snippet to recreate the bug.

Basically, above snippet create a chart with some random data. I have also got a checkbox where user can enable/disable zoom and pan on chart. Initially created chart has no zoomable/pannable set.

See in Action:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/pan-and-zoom">
  <style>
    html {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example">

    <div class="box wide">

      <input type="checkbox" id="eq1" class="k-checkbox">
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="eq1">Enable Zoom</label>
      <p id="para">Use SHIFT + Mouse Drag Region Selection combination on mouse-enabled devices to zoom in data for a specific period of time</p>

    </div>
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
      <div id="chart"></div>
      <div id="log" style="
            height: 120px;
            overflow: scroll;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      // Sample data
      var data = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var val = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
        data.push({
          category: "C" + i,
          value: val
        });
      }

      function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
          renderAs: "canvas",
          dataSource: {
            data: data
          },
          categoryAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            labels: {
              rotation: "auto"
            }
          },
          series: [{
            type: "column",
            field: "value",
            categoryField: "category"
          }]

        });
      }

      $(document).ready(createChart);
      $("#example").bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);

      $("#eq1").click(function(e) {
        if (this.checked) {
          setZoom({
            pannable: {
              lock: "y"
            },
            zoomable: {
              mousewheel: {
                lock: "y"
              },
              selection: {
                lock: "y"
              }
            }
          });
        } else {
          setZoom({
            pannable: false,
            zoomable: false
          });
        }
      });

      function setZoom(obj) {
        try {
          $("#chart").data("kendoChart").setOptions(obj);
        } catch (ex) {
          $('#log').append($('<div/>').text("Error : " + ex.message + "\n" + ex.stack + "\n"));
        }
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

On user interacting with checkbox (top left corner), zoomable and pannable properties of the chart being set using chart.setOptions() method available in the framework. If the "**Run Code Snippet**" does not work, please follow the following steps, you can see the bug in action.

Step 1: Copy above snippet into editor at http://dojo.telerik.com/ 
Step 2: Run the code. (A chart gets created as a result)

Step 3: Tick the checkbox to enable the zoom for chart. (zoomable and pannable properties sets on x-axis so that chart can now be zoomable and pannable)

Step 4: Untick the checkbox to disable the zoom for chart. (pannable gets disabled, but chart still can be zoomable. - this is the bug)

Step 5: Tick the checkbox again and you will see the error which shows up under the chart.

If anyone know how to resolve this. If this is the bug with KendoUI then hope Kendo development team gets this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange, for anyone looking for a work-around you can use prevent default on the events:

```
...
          zoom: preventThisPlease,
          dragStart: preventThisPlease,
...

      function preventThisPlease(e) {
        if (! document.getElementById('eq1').checked) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }        
      }
```

With a refresh on the checkbox change to reset the zoom level and pan location if you need:

```
  $("#eq1").click(function(e) {
    $("#chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
  });
```

**UPDATE: (To change the chart configuration options).**
It appears that the problems occur when we try to set pannable or zoomable to false. So adapting on the solution to use prevent default to disable pan/zoom, we are able to alter the options of the chart. See code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/pan-and-zoom">
  <style>
    html {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example">

    <div class="box wide">

      <form class="chart-switch">
        Restrict Pan & Zoom to:

        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="eq1" class="k-radio">
        <label class="k-radio-label" for="eq1">X</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="eq2" class="k-radio">
        <label class="k-radio-label" for="eq2">Y</label>         

        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="eq3" class="k-radio">
        <label class="k-radio-label" for="eq3">X & Y</label>  

        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="eq4" class="k-radio" checked>
        <label class="k-radio-label" for="eq4">None</label>
      </form>        
      

      <p id="para">Use SHIFT + Mouse Drag Region Selection combination on mouse-enabled devices to zoom in data for a specific period of time</p>

    </div>
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
      <div id="chart"></div>
      <div id="log" style="
            height: 120px;
            overflow: scroll;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      // Sample data
      var data = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var val = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
        data.push({
          category: "C" + i,
          value: val
        });
      }

      function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
          renderAs: "canvas",
          dataSource: {
            data: data
          },
          categoryAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            labels: {
              rotation: "auto"
            }
          },
          series: [{
            type: "column",
            field: "value",
            categoryField: "category"
          }],
          zoom: preventThisPlease,
          dragStart: preventThisPlease,
          pannable: {
              lock: "x"
            },
            zoomable: {
              mousewheel: {
                lock: "x"
              },
              selection: {
                lock: "x"
              }
            }

        });
      }

      $(document).ready(createChart);
      $("#example").bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);

// Disable Pan/Zoom
      function preventThisPlease(e) {
        if (document.getElementById('eq4').checked) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }        
      }      

// Pan/Zoom options changing
      $(".chart-switch  input").on('change', function(e) {

        // Get reference to the chart
        var theChart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");

        // See which radio button is checked
        var radioId = $(e.target).attr('id');
        var toLock = "none";

        switch(radioId) {
          case "eq1":
            toLock = "y";
            break;
          case "eq2":
            toLock = "x";
            break;
          default:
            toLock = "none";
        }

        try {
          theChart.options.pannable.lock = toLock;
          theChart.options.zoomable.mousewheel.lock = toLock;
          theChart.options.zoomable.selection.lock = toLock;

          theChart.refresh();   
        } catch (ex) {
          $('#log').append($('<div/>').text("Error : " + ex.message + "\n" + ex.stack + "\n"));
        }

      });   

    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Glen, that is possible workaround. But It works only if I want to lock ONLY x axis or ONLY y axis. Now I have a problem where I want both  x axis and y axis to be zoomed and panned! That is the reason I want to use setOptions() method available in the chart widget. I just want to give the user a flexibility so that user can do following: a) Zoom x axis, b) zoom y axis c) zoom x and y axis, d) disable zoom on both x and y axis.
 How do I achieve that?

Comment: It seems the error we're getting is due to setting pannable or zoomable to false, so keeping my "hack" to prevent default action when you want to disable pan/zoom I'm able to change the options of the chart like:
theChart.options.pannable.lock = "x";

I'll post a working code snippet as an answer.

Comment: That is great, works perfectly. Thank you so very much.:)